# Do Find My devices (eg AirTag) know when they are being pinged?

Tags: ios, airtag

Normally one thinks of an AirTag as a blackbox, but with 3rd party Find My applications appearing I'm wondering if there is API that lets the "tag" know it's being queried, especially by a particular device?

I have an idea for a small device that would spend 95% of its time sleeping and only activate when a particular device came close. I was going to do this with BT, but I'm wondering if Find My could replace this as the device needs that support anyway (it *will* be lost on occasion).

Comment: There are two ways that find my finds an airtag. First, your device tries to establish a Bluetooth connection with the device and use wideband comms to help you locate it. You can also get it to make a sound. This only works if your device and the airtag are within Bluetooth range (say 30m). The Find My app can also query Apple's servers to see if there is a known location. How that works is described [in this article](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2019/06/the-clever-cryptography-behind-apples-find-my-feature/). In this case the airtag does not know it is being "pinged"

Comment: That article describes how "find my Mac" etc work but I imagine the process is much the same for Airtags. 3rd parties can license Apples AirTag protocols to embed in their own devices but I haven't seen any public api that lets you query the find my database for item locations.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that does suggest the "particular device" (in this case, an ipad) would locate the tag but the tag would not know it was *that* ipad. That's a bit of an annoyance, but not fatal. Thanks again.